# Run time error 1004 App-defined or object-defined error When working on ThisWorkbook with .Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm adding a new line to a table each time a new sheet is added to the workbook, that's why I write the code in `ThisWorkbook` - event `NewSheet`. In order to modify the formula that is automatically written in the new line to make it search the data in a new sheet, I loop through the columns and replace "2013" with the actual year (which is the new sheet name).
The first time the code is run it goes perfectly. Then the second time it returns the error.
I have been looking in the forum for days but couldn't find the answer. I'm using Excel 2016.

I have tried several things but really without theoretical knowledge.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Stop
    Dim lastfileStudyYear, lastfileSponsorYear, lastfileAnalythics As Long
    Dim i, uformula, lastyear, currentyear, newformula
    Dim StudyYear, SponsorYear, Analythics As ListObject
    Set StudyYear = Worksheets("Datos KPI").ListObjects("StudyvsYear")
    Set SponsorsAño = Worksheets("Datos KPI").ListObjects("SponsorsvsYear")
    Set Analythics = Worksheets("Datos KPI").ListObjects("Analythics")

    lastfileStudyYear = StudyYear.Range.Rows.Count + 1
    Worksheets("Datos KPI").Rows(lastfileStudyYear).Insert

    lastyear= Worksheets("Datos KPI").Cells(lastfileStudyYear- 1, 1).Value
    currentyear = lastyear + 1

    Worksheets("Datos KPI").Cells(lastfileStudyYear, 1).Value = currentyear 

    colStudyYear = StudyYear.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count

    For i = 2 To colStudyYear 
        newformula = StudyYear.DataBodyRange.Cells(lastfileStudyYear- 1, i).Formula
        newformula = Replace(newformula, "2013", currentyear)
        StudyYear.DataBodyRange.Cells(lastfileStudyYear- 1, i).Formula = newformula '<- HERE IS THE ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!
    Next
```

I expect the formula in the `Cell(lastfileStudyYear- 1, i)` to change from
`=COUNTIF(Estudios2013[FA],"x")`
to `=COUNTIF(Estudios2020[FA],"x")`

But the actual output is a ERROR.
Many thanks!

Comment: add this before the line that errors: `newformula = Replace(newformula, Char(34), Char(34) & Char(34))`  the quotes in the string need to be doubled.

Comment: You don't need a loop to `Replace`, you can just use `Range.Replace`.

Comment: Also, when you are declaring multiple variables on a single line, each of those variable should include the type individually. Otherwise, those variables without a type will be declared as `Variant`. So your line should be `Dim StudyYear As ListObject, SponsorYear As ListObject, Analythics As ListObject`.

Comment: @ScottCraner no not if they are in a variable. They only need to be doubled if you hardcode a string with quotes in the code itself.

Comment: @nicolas Make sure that the formula is correct and the address does exist. Check `Debug.Print newformula` right before the error line and check if this contains the desired formula. Probably the `Estudios` for `currentyear` don't exist.

Comment: You set `currentyear = añoprevio + 1` but as far as I see you don't declare nor initialize `añoprevio`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ genius! That's exactly what was happening. It wasn't a code problem, but excel couldn't find Estudios2020 because it didn't exist. It's a table that's named after adding the new sheet. Thanks so much!

Comment: @FunThomas yes sorry, i have corrected it. The real variables are in spanish, I translated them just for this post.